# Best way to check if a Model exists in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have some data being posted to the server and am retrieving a `Player` based on that data (an id). I am using the following code:

```
$player = Player::findOrFail($player_data['id']);
```

However, I want to check that this `Player` belongs to a specific `Team` - a `belongsToMany` relationship.

Is there a better way than something like:

```
if (! count($player->team()->find($teamId))) {
    // exit early, form may have been 'hacked'
    abort(404);
}
```

?

**`team()` and not `teams()`, even though its a many-to-many.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method:

```
$player->team->contains($teamId);
```

> The contains method determines whether the collection contains a given item

Comment: Thank you! So, passing an ```id``` to ```contains``` is appropriate?

Comment: @AshMenhennet, although it is possible but may become pitfall, i suggest retrieve the team first and pass it as parameter. look at the second example in the link..

Comment: @AshMenhennett yes, it's appropriate.