# How can I check matching two values in a pivot table?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$role_id = Auth::user()->role_id;
$page_id = Page::where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first()->id;
```

So I have both `role_id` and `page_id`. Also I have a table like this:

```
// role_pages
+---------+---------+
| role_id | page_id |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       |
| 1       | 2       |
| 1       | 4       |
| 1       | 8       |
| 2       | 1       |
| 2       | 3       |
| 2       | 7       |
| 3       | 1       |
| 3       | 9       |
+---------+---------+
```

Noted that there is an composite unique index on `role_pages(role_id, page_id)`. And as you can see, the logic is: each role has multiple pages.

Anyway, how can I check is there any row in table above according to my values? Noted that I can do that in pure SQL by using `EXISTS()` function. But I want to know how can I do that in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check is there any row in table

Use the [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713730/best-way-to-check-if-a-model-exists-in-a-many-to-many-relationship).

Example:

```
$page = Page::where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first();
$page->roles()->contains(Auth::user()->role_id);
```

Or:

```
$role = auth()->user()->role;
$pageId = Page::where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first()->id;
$role->pages()->contains($pageId);
```

Comment: what's `roles()` ?

Comment: @stack `roles()` and `pages()` are many to many relationships (`belongsToMany`) defined in your models.

Comment: Ah ... Should I define them manually in the model or they are defined by default?

Comment: @stack you need to define those. Here's an example https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I see, thank you .. just the vague part in your solution is: you didn't use `role_pages` table at all. That's the pivot table that I want to check is a matched row in it.

Comment: @stack you don't use the table directly here if you want to use Eloquent. Also, it's better to follow [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) and call the pivot table `page_role`